# python throwing ImportError while running from apache

Tags: python, apache, redhat, cgi-bin

I have a python script in my cgi-bin where I am calling another perl script which in turn calls a python script to perform some tests. It works perfectly fine when I run it from the command line, but throws import error: no module named paramiko when I run from Apache. I have even printed:

```
import site
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient
```

in my python script, but I get an error when I run from browser.

My python code which calls the perl script is as below:

```
def execute_ACL():
    print "Going to execute"
    for line in run_command("perl systemtcpcheck.pl acl/config_files/G2AXStageg2ax-stage.hosts acl/config_files/G2AXStageg2ax-live.tests"):
        print(line)
def run_command(command):
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return p.communicate()
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution ?

Comment: Are you sure that 'paramiko' package is in that directory?. You can try: print(paramiko.__file__)

Comment: Yea it is in that directory.